# Find Top Summed Subvalue by Name and State in Excel

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I have an Excel table with states, names, and counts.  I am trying to find the top name by sum of the count for each state.  So, for example, with the following:

```
State | Name     | Count
IA    | Joe      | 10
IA    | John     | 10
IA    | Joe      | 5
NE    | Joe      | 5
NE    | John     | 10
NE    | John     | 15
NE    | Joe      | 10
NE    | Amy      | 30
OH    | Joe      | 10
OH    | John     | 10
OH    | Amy      | 5
OH    | Joe      | 5
```

The expected results would be:

```
IA | Joe (15)
NE | Amy (30)
OH | Joe (15)
```

Any ideas on how to do this?  Maybe something with pivot tables?

Comment: Why wouldn't NE include Amy in your example both are 25

Comment: Good catch - adjusted my example numbers.  The real spreadsheet has several thousand rows, so this is just an example, and I made a mistake on it.  Edited the post to correct.

Comment: Could you remove my down-vote as I corrected the post?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Couple of approaches stand out

1) use 2 pivots one that has row labels  of name and states as column labels and sums the values.  Second pivot is based on first pivot uses lists names as row labels and max of state as values, then use conditional formatting to high light those with the same grand total.
[image]

2nd option is similar to first but instead of using second pivot have seperate values for each state that have the formula (=max) of the state in the pivot then base the conditional formatting on that.

3rd option would be define it as a table and then use embedded SQL with the form to write a query to give you the sum and max by state  Don't have an example of that one yet.